# Beginner CSS: Text-Alignment on 3 Footer columns with the same div container

Tags: css

I'm a total beginner in web-building making my first website.

I am currently working on my footer design where I would like to have 3 columns (left, middle, right). The left will have a link to my Whatsapp, the middle where I will place the logo, and the right where I will place the Instagram.

For design perspective, the left column will be aligned to the left; the middle will be aligned center, and the right to the right (image attached).

I managed to preview how I want them to be via the Inspector feature on Chrome, but translating it onto CSS is another issue for me. The left and right column is contained within the same container. If I make the container left-aligned, it will work on my left column but will make the right column wrong, vice versa. To make things worse, the middle part is also contained within the same container.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot for your help. Please find below the relevant screenshots

1. Current Footer 
   [image]
2. Intended Footer 
   [image]
3. Screenshot of all 3 columns sharing the same div container

center
[image]

left
[image]

right
[image]

Comment: Please share css code as well please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can style your elements using flex. and change the layout as you want.

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <footer class="">
    <div style="width:30%; border: solid 1px;">
      left element
    </div>
    <div style="width:60%; border: solid 1px;">
      center element
    </div>
    <div style="width:20%; border: solid 1px;">
      right element
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: ````<body>
  <footer class="">
    <div style="width:30%; border: solid 1px;">
      left element
    </div>
    <div style="width:60%; border: solid 1px;">
      center element
    </div>
    <div style="width:20%; border: solid 1px;">
      right element
    </div>
</body>````

for this part I assume I have to edit the child theme or is it editable via CSS? Sorry for the redundant question!

Comment: I have shared the idea with you. You need to put your valid HTML markup(elements) here and check if your requirement is met!

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dummy</title>
<style>
#footer {
    display: table;
    max-width: 60em;
    padding: 1.25em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
 }

#footer div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.333%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

#footer div h2 {
    text-align: center;
 }

#footer div:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
 }

#footer div:nth-of-type(3) {
    text-align: left;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body> 
 <div id="footer">
  <div>
    <h2>Left</h2>
    <p>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  </div><div>
    <h2>Center:</h2>
    <p>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  </div><div>
    <h2>Right:</h2>
    <p>Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```